# Size of pointer array in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sizeof

[image]

`Int *ptr = new int[3];`

How many bytes will this array occupy in RAM?

And `ptr` gives 8 bytes, while `*ptr` gives 4, I'm confused, so the total bytes the pointers takes is 8 bytes on 32 bit (excluding the other array indexes only pointer)?

Comment: Size of an array = size of one element times number of elements = `sizeof(int) * 3`

Comment: `sizeof(*ptr)` is just the size of a single integer. If you want to double-check the size of the whole array, just use `int array[3]; sizeof(array)` to avoid pointer decay.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Allocation: *Array allocation may supply **unspecified overhead**, which may vary from one call to new to the next, unless the allocation function selected is the standard non-allocating form.*

Comment: `sizeof(ptr)` is the same as `sizeof(int*)`; `sizeof(*ptr)` is the same is `sizeof(int)`. Neither is the same as `sizeof(int[3])`.

Comment: Yeah - the total size in RAM of the dynamically-allocated version includes some housekeeping overhead. There's no way to inspect that.

Comment: please show the code for how you got `8` and `4`. We can guess, but adding the code would make the question more answerable (or more dupe closable...;)

Comment: On my system (not my experimental DS9K system), the `sizeof(int[3])` is 12, and `sizeof(int*)` is 8.  But the housekeeping of the `new` is 16 bytes, and the minimum allocation size is 32 bytes, so of the 12 bytes there are also 20 fallow bytes.  Grand total 8 + 32 + 16 = 56 bytes.

Comment: i'm kinda confused, correct me if i'm wrong. 5 indexes take 20 bytes(4 x 5) and the pointer takes 4 bytes too making a total of 24 ?

Comment: @Aveloni `int[5]` takes up `sizeof(int) * 5` bytes, `ptr` takes up `sizeof(int*)` bytes, and `new[]` can also require unspecified amounts of additional bookkeeping memory. The value of `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(int*)` and of `new[]`'s book keeping memory requirement are all implementation specific. It depends what platform you are building for. Furthermore, some objects may never actually make it to RAM. They might live entirely in a CPU register or otherwise be optimized out. There is no single correct answer to your question. It depends.

Comment: *i'm kinda confused*  The answer depends on what you are actually trying to measure.  `sizeof(*a)` will give you the size of a single `int`.  `new int[3];` in your question is different from `new int[5];` in your code image.

Comment: oops.. changed the array size in the image my bad

Comment: one thing more... int *ptr;  ------> this has not been assigned a memory adress right ?(have to explicitely assign it with 'new int'), but it gives me same size i.e. 8 bytes as int* ptr  = new int;